# Playing Sound in C# - which of all ways to use?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, audio

I'm trying to write a little C# .net - application that plays sounds randomly from folders when specific buttons are clicked.

So I spend some time finding the right way to realise that. In my head "just playing a sound" didn't seem to be as complicated, but there are a lot of ways to do that.

Please correct me in every thing I'm going to say now:

- [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712879.aspx) is the pretty old way, no controls like volume, multiple sounds or looping
- [mciSendString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), sending text comments to an MCI, playing different formats, supporting Volumecontrol, even multiple sounds at the same time are possible, not very confortable sending string commands instead of using class, might need a wellformed wrapper class (anybody? :D )
- [SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171679.aspx) class, supports async, no real further thing, no volume no looping
- [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms635239.aspx) class, supports even more than audio, .net 4.0, volume, but needs some "special treatment" to work with multiple sounds at the same time
- [DirectSound](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2008/12/25/capturing-and-streaming-sound-by-using-directsound-with-c.aspx), seems to support everything you can imagine with sound, code looks way too complicated for "simply play a sound"

Okay, that are the ways, maybe I'm missing one, but in general... I'm not convinced by one yet.

I want to start, stop, pause custom .wav .mp3 sounds not just after each other but sometimes even at the same time, change there volume during they are running and maybe some mute function stopping all sounds. Sounds easy, but is it?

Thanks for any hints in advance,

Harry

Answer (score 1):

Does it make more sense for your requirement to start a new Windows Media player process with the specified sound file loaded? 
You can get this done using the System.Diagnostics.Process class

```
Process.Start("wmplayer.exe", "C:\\myPath\\mySound.mp3");
```

Comment: ok, this is another method to simply start a sound. Not very comfy either :|

Answer (score 1):

You can use media player control in WPF which is pretty easy to use and customize to your needs.

If you are just using windows forms you can use windows media player ActiveX control and customize it a little to have your own UI for play/Pause/Forward/Rewind etc.

DirectX would be little difficult for one to develop compared to above two options.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, actually I'm using "just" :D Windows Forms

Answer (score 1):

I extended a class i found here: [Playing MP3s using MCI http://www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Example.aspx)
and made it easy usable with multiple sounds which stay controlable.

Its pretty much self-explanatory, but maybe somebody somewhen finding this thread safes some time using this piece of code or maybe there are some major things to improve it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace someNameHere
{
    public class MP3Player
    {
        private string Pcommand, FName,alias;
        private bool Opened, Playing, Paused, Loop,
                     MutedAll, MutedLeft, MutedRight;
        private int rVolume, lVolume, aVolume,
                    tVolume, bVolume, VolBalance;
        private ulong Lng;
        private long Err;
        private static int counter = 0;
        public static List<MP3Player> currentlyActive = new List<MP3Player>();
        public static List<MP3Player> lastFiveActive = new List<MP3Player>();

        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand,
                StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength,
                IntPtr hwndCallback);

        public MP3Player()
        {
            Opened = false;
            Pcommand = "";
            FName = "";
            Playing = false;
            Paused = false;
            Loop = false;
            MutedAll = MutedLeft = MutedRight = false;
            rVolume = lVolume = aVolume =
                      tVolume = bVolume = 1000;
            Lng = 0;
            VolBalance = 0;
            Err = 0;
            counter++;
            alias = "alias" + counter.ToString();
            currentlyActive = cleanUpActive();
            currentlyActive.Add(this);
        }

         ~MP3Player()
        {
            currentlyActive.Remove(this);
        }


        private List<MP3Player> cleanUpActive()
        {
            List<MP3Player> cachedList = new List<MP3Player>(currentlyActive);
            cachedList = (from c in cachedList where c.AudioLength == c.CurrentPosition select c).ToList();

            foreach (MP3Player eachSound in cachedList)
            {
                eachSound.Stop();
                eachSound.Close();
            }

            return (from c in currentlyActive where c.AudioLength != c.CurrentPosition select c).ToList();
        }

         public static void playRandomFromFolder(string relpath, bool checkIfInLast)
         {
             try
             {
                 string currentdir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                 string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(currentdir + relpath);
                 Random randNum = new Random();
                 List<string> list_paths = (from c in lastFiveActive select c.FileName).ToList();

                 string randomFile = "";
                 int i = 0;
                 while (true)
                 {
                     int zufall = randNum.Next(0, Files.Length);
                     if (!list_paths.Contains(Files[zufall]) || i > 10)
                     {
                         randomFile = Files[zufall];
                         break;
                     }

                 }

                 MP3Player playIt = new MP3Player();
                 playIt.Open(randomFile);
                 playIt.Play();
             }
             catch (Exception err)
             {
               //  MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
             }

         }



        #region AllActiveFunctions

        public static void stopAllActive()
        {
            List<MP3Player> cachedList = new List<MP3Player>(currentlyActive);
            foreach (MP3Player eachSound in cachedList)
            {
                eachSound.Stop();
            }

        }
        public static void pauseAllActive()
        {
            foreach (MP3Player eachSound in currentlyActive)
            {
                eachSound.Pause();
            }

        }
        public static void playAllActive()
        {
            List<MP3Player> cachedList = new List<MP3Player>(currentlyActive);
            foreach (MP3Player eachSound in cachedList)
            {
                eachSound.Play();
            }

        }
        public static void setVolumeAllActive(int i)
        {
            List<MP3Player> cachedList = new List<MP3Player>(currentlyActive);
            foreach (MP3Player eachSound in cachedList)
            {
                eachSound.VolumeAll = i;
            }

        }
        public static void setVolumeLeft(int i)
        {
            List<MP3Player> cachedList = new List<MP3Player>(currentlyActive);
            foreach (MP3Player eachSound in cachedList)
            {
                eachSound.VolumeLeft = i;
            }

        }
        public static void setVolumeRight(int i)
        {
            List<MP3Player> cachedList = new List<MP3Player>(currentlyActive);
            foreach (MP3Player eachSound in cachedList)
            {
                eachSound.VolumeRight = i;
            }

        }
        public static void setVolumeTreble(int i)
        {
            List<MP3Player> cachedList = new List<MP3Player>(currentlyActive);
            foreach (MP3Player eachSound in cachedList)
            {
                eachSound.VolumeTreble = i;
            }

        }
        public static void setVolumeBass(int i)
        {
            List<MP3Player> cachedList = new List<MP3Player>(currentlyActive);
            foreach (MP3Player eachSound in cachedList)
            {
                eachSound.VolumeBass = i;
            }

        }

        public static void setBalance(int i)
        {
            List<MP3Player> cachedList = new List<MP3Player>(currentlyActive);
            foreach (MP3Player eachSound in cachedList)
            {
                eachSound.Balance = i;
            }

        }

        public static void stopLast()
        {
            List<MP3Player> cachedList = new List<MP3Player>(currentlyActive);
            cachedList.Last().Stop();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Volume
        public bool MuteAll
        {
            get
            {
                return MutedAll;
            }
            set
            {
                MutedAll = value;
                if (MutedAll)
                {
                    Pcommand = "setaudio " + alias + " off";
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
                else
                {
                    Pcommand = "setaudio " + alias + " on";
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
            }

        }

        public bool MuteLeft
        {
            get
            {
                return MutedLeft;
            }
            set
            {
                MutedLeft = value;
                if (MutedLeft)
                {
                    Pcommand = "setaudio " + alias + " left off";
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
                else
                {
                    Pcommand = "setaudio " + alias + " left on";
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
            }

        }

        public bool MuteRight
        {
            get
            {
                return MutedRight;
            }
            set
            {
                MutedRight = value;
                if (MutedRight)
                {
                    Pcommand = "setaudio " + alias + " right off";
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
                else
                {
                    Pcommand = "setaudio " + alias + " right on";
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
            }

        }

        public int VolumeAll
        {
            get
            {
                return aVolume;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Opened && (value >= 0 && value <= 1000))
                {
                    aVolume = value;
                    Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio " + alias + "" +
                               " volume to {0}", aVolume);
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0,
                                          IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
            }
        }

        public int VolumeLeft
        {
            get
            {
                return lVolume;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Opened && (value >= 0 && value <= 1000))
                {
                    lVolume = value;
                    Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio " + alias + "" +
                               " left volume to {0}", lVolume);
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0,
                                           IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
            }
        }

        public int VolumeRight
        {
            get
            {
                return rVolume;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Opened && (value >= 0 && value <= 1000))
                {
                    rVolume = value;
                    Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio" +
                               " " + alias + " right volume to {0}", rVolume);
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
            }
        }

        public int VolumeTreble
        {
            get
            {
                return tVolume;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Opened && (value >= 0 && value <= 1000))
                {
                    tVolume = value;
                    Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio " + alias + "" +
                                             " treble to {0}", tVolume);
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
            }
        }

        public int VolumeBass
        {
            get
            {
                return bVolume;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Opened && (value >= 0 && value <= 1000))
                {
                    bVolume = value;
                    Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio " + alias + " bass to {0}",
                                             bVolume);
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                }
            }
        }

        public int Balance
        {
            get
            {
                return VolBalance;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Opened && (value >= -1000 && value <= 1000))
                {
                    VolBalance = value;
                    if (value < 0)
                    {
                        Pcommand = "setaudio " + alias + " left volume to 1000";
                        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                            OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                        Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio " + alias + " right" +
                                                 " volume to {0}", 1000 + value);
                        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                            OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Pcommand = "setaudio " + alias + " right volume to 1000";
                        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                            OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                        Pcommand = String.Format("setaudio " + alias + "" +
                                   " left volume to {0}", 1000 - value);
                        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                            OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Main Functions

        public string FileName
        {
            get
            {
                return FName;
            }
        }

        public bool Looping
        {
            get
            {
                return Loop;
            }
            set
            {
                Loop = value;
            }
        }

        public void Seek(ulong Millisecs)
        {
            if (Opened && Millisecs <= Lng)
            {
                if (Playing)
                {
                    if (Paused)
                    {
                        Pcommand = String.Format("seek " + alias + " to {0}", Millisecs);
                        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                            OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Pcommand = String.Format("seek " + alias + " to {0}", Millisecs);
                        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                            OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                        Pcommand = "play " + alias + "";
                        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                            OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void CalculateLength()
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(128);
            mciSendString("status " + alias + " length", str, 128, IntPtr.Zero);
            Lng = Convert.ToUInt64(str.ToString());
        }

        public ulong AudioLength
        {
            get
            {
                if (Opened) return Lng;
                else return 0;
            }
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            if (Opened)
            {
                Pcommand = "close " + alias + "";
                if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                    OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                Opened = false;
                Playing = false;
                Paused = false;
                OnCloseFile(new CloseFileEventArgs());
            }
        }

        public void Open(string sFileName)
        {
            if (!Opened)
            {
                Pcommand = "open \"" + sFileName +
                           "\" type mpegvideo alias " + alias + "";
                if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                    OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                FName = sFileName;
                Opened = true;
                Playing = false;
                Paused = false;
                Pcommand = "set " + alias + " time format milliseconds";
                if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                    OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                Pcommand = "set " + alias + " seek exactly on";
                if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                    OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                CalculateLength();
                OnOpenFile(new OpenFileEventArgs(sFileName));
            }
            else
            {
                this.Close();
                this.Open(sFileName);
            }
        }

        private void stackLastFive(MP3Player latest)
        {
            if (lastFiveActive.Count() > 5)
            {
              lastFiveActive.Reverse();
              lastFiveActive = lastFiveActive.Take(4).ToList();
            }
            lastFiveActive.Add(latest);

        }

        public void Play()
        {
            if (Opened)
            {
                if (!Playing)
                {
                    Playing = true;
                    Pcommand = "play " + alias + "";
                    if (Loop) Pcommand += " REPEAT";
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                    OnPlayFile(new PlayFileEventArgs());
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!Paused)
                    {
                        Pcommand = "seek " + alias + " to start";
                        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                            OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                        Pcommand = "play " + alias + "";
                        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                            OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                        OnPlayFile(new PlayFileEventArgs());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Paused = false;
                        Pcommand = "play " + alias + "";
                        if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                            OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                        OnPlayFile(new PlayFileEventArgs());
                    }
                }
                stackLastFive(this);
            }
        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            if (Opened)
            {
                if (!Paused)
                {
                    Paused = true;
                    Pcommand = "pause " + alias + "";
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                    OnPauseFile(new PauseFileEventArgs());
                }
                else
                {
                    Paused = false;
                    Pcommand = "play " + alias + "";
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                    OnPlayFile(new PlayFileEventArgs());
                }
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (Opened && Playing)
            {
                Playing = false;
                Paused = false;
                Pcommand = "seek " + alias + " to start";
                if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                    OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                Pcommand = "stop " + alias + "";
                if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                    OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                currentlyActive.Remove(this);
                OnStopFile(new StopFileEventArgs());
            }
        }

        public ulong CurrentPosition
        {
            get
            {
                if (Opened && Playing)
                {
                    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(128);
                    Pcommand = "status " + alias + " position";
                    if ((Err = mciSendString(Pcommand, s, 128, IntPtr.Zero)) != 0)
                        OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(Err));
                    return Convert.ToUInt64(s.ToString());
                }
                else return 0;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Event Handling

        public delegate void OpenFileEventHandler(Object sender,
                             OpenFileEventArgs oea);

        public delegate void PlayFileEventHandler(Object sender,
                             PlayFileEventArgs pea);

        public delegate void PauseFileEventHandler(Object sender,
                             PauseFileEventArgs paea);

        public delegate void StopFileEventHandler(Object sender,
                                         StopFileEventArgs sea);

        public delegate void CloseFileEventHandler(Object sender,
                                         CloseFileEventArgs cea);

        public delegate void ErrorEventHandler(Object sender,
                                         ErrorEventArgs eea);

        public event OpenFileEventHandler OpenFile;

        public event PlayFileEventHandler PlayFile;

        public event PauseFileEventHandler PauseFile;

        public event StopFileEventHandler StopFile;

        public event CloseFileEventHandler CloseFile;

        public event ErrorEventHandler Error;

        protected virtual void OnOpenFile(OpenFileEventArgs oea)
        {
            if (OpenFile != null) OpenFile(this, oea);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPlayFile(PlayFileEventArgs pea)
        {
            if (PlayFile != null) PlayFile(this, pea);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPauseFile(PauseFileEventArgs paea)
        {
            if (PauseFile != null) PauseFile(this, paea);
        }

        protected virtual void OnStopFile(StopFileEventArgs sea)
        {
            if (StopFile != null) StopFile(this, sea);
        }

        protected virtual void OnCloseFile(CloseFileEventArgs cea)
        {
            if (CloseFile != null) CloseFile(this, cea);
            if (currentlyActive.Contains(this))
            {
                currentlyActive.Remove(this);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnError(ErrorEventArgs eea)
        {
            if (Error != null) Error(this, eea);
        }


    }

    public class OpenFileEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public OpenFileEventArgs(string filename)
        {
            this.FileName = filename;
        }
        public readonly string FileName;
    }

    public class PlayFileEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public PlayFileEventArgs()
        {

        }
    }

    public class PauseFileEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public PauseFileEventArgs()
        {
        }
    }

    public class StopFileEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public StopFileEventArgs()
        {
        }
    }

    public class CloseFileEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public CloseFileEventArgs()
        {
        }
    }

    public class ErrorEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public ErrorEventArgs(long Err)
        {
            this.ErrNum = Err;
        }

        public readonly long ErrNum;
    }
     #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that `MediaPlayer` class is the most robust and also the simplest one to use. I have done some audio/video playback and you can do almost anything with it. Since you need to play multiple files `SoundPlayer` is the obvious choice, so you can probably do a mix of both.
However, you can have multiple instances of MediaPlayer and play different sounds like that.

It also seems like you have already done the research and can pretty much answer your question best.